# logstash : how to extract data from log4j message?

Tags: log4j, logstash

I try to extract data from my log4j message with logstash. 
The message look like this :

```
Method findAll - Start by : bokc
```

I would like to extract the method name : "findAll" and the user "bokc".

How can I do this?

I use logstash 1.5.2 and my config is :

```
input {
    log4j {
        mode => "server"
        type => "log4j-artemis"
        port => 4560
    }
}

filter {
  multiline {
    type => "log4j-artemis"
    pattern => "^\\s"
    what => "previous"
  }
  mutate {
    add_field => [ "source_ip", "%{host}" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the grok filter? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to use it to add a field. The log4j input give me fields that I want. I just want to add the 2 fields (method name and user) without rewrite all the filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html):

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => [
      "message",
      "^Method %{WORD:method} - Start by : %{USER:user}"
    ]
    tag_on_failure => []
  }
}
```

This extracts the two words into the fields "method" and "user". The setting of `tag_on_failure` makes sure that non-matching messages aren't tagged with `_grokparsefailure`. Since most messages aren't *supposed* to match the pattern it doesn't make sense to mark them as failures.